# Automating C++ debugging from IntelliJ Java

Tags: java, c++, debugging, intellij-idea, clion

Currently, when working on a project with mixed Java and C++ code, I have to run the application in IntelliJ and manually attach the CLion debugger to the JVM process.

Is there a way to automate these steps so that I can run the application from IntelliJ and a CLion or Visual Studio debugger is automatically attached?

I suspect this may only be possible with a plugin similar to how VisualVM is integrated with IntelliJ.

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how your Java and C++ code interacts.

If it's a JNI library, you can create a [run configuration](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/run-debug-configuration.html) for CLion where the [Java process is the executable](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/clion/creating-and-editing-run-debug-configurations.html#createExplicitly), and C++ library is being debugged.